# Textbox click on page load Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

As i'm using Kendo UI Grid to get the textbox it uses search option when clicked enter after typing.
Here is the image below:
[image: text box click]

I want to click text box when page loads here is the code which i did.

```
$('input[data-text-field="CompanyName"]').val('lewis');

    console.log($('input[data-text-field="CompanyName"]'));

    $('input[data-text-field="CompanyName"]').click();

    $('input[data-text-field="CompanyName"]').select();
```

neither click works and select on page load for text box only it loads the text as you can see.
On click page this `$('input[data-text-field="CompanyName"]').select();` works but not on the page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use the grid's [databound event](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound). Then set the first cell (or whichever) to [current](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/current):

```
function dataBound(e) {
    var cell = this.tbody.find("tr[role='row'] td:first");
    this.current(cell);
    this.table.focus();
}
```

Comment: i actually require to auto click the text box on page load when value is present.

Comment: found a solution to it.